# Not continuous function with closed graph

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

I would like to see an explicit example of a function $f:R\rightarrow R$ which has a closed graph in $R^2$ but is discontinuous at every point in the real line.

Comment: [There is no such thing](http://calculus7.org/2015/02/07/nonlinear-closed-graph-theorem/)

Comment: @woodface why's that?